# How to calculate totals before_save in has_many through relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been struggling with this problem since the morning and it is 3:00 am in my country now.

Simply I have a Bill model:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :bill_lines, inverse_of: :bill
  validates_associated :bill_lines

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_lines, allow_destroy: true

  after_validation :calculate_totals

  def calculate_totals
    self.total = self.bill_lines.sum(:total)
    self.tax_total = self.bill_lines.sum(:tax_total)
    self.grand_total = self.bill_lines.sum(:grand_total)
  end

end
```

And also:

```
class BillLine < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :bill, inverse_of: :bill_lines
  has_many :bill_line_taxes
  has_many :taxes, through: :bill_line_taxes
  validates_associated :bill_line_taxes

  validates :bill, presence: true
  validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: true
  validates :price, presence: true, numericality: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bill_line_taxes, allow_destroy: true 

  after_validation :calculate_totals

  def calculate_totals
    self.total = self.price * self.quantity
    self.grand_total = self.total
    self.taxes.each do |tax|
      rate = Tax.find(tax.id).tax_rate
      self.grand_total = self.grand_total + ( rate / 100 ) * self.grand_total
    end
    self.tax_total = self.grand_total - self.total
    true
  end

end
```

I am getting as result:

```
bill = FactoryGirl.create(:bill)
bill.total # 50.0 as expected
bill.tax_total # 0.0
bill.grand_total # 50.0
```

I tried self.taxes.each and self.bill_line_taxes.each and many of the callbacks like after_save, before_validation etc. I cannot reach the tax ids in my callbacks. But the associations are saved to database properly. If I validate code bill.bill_lines.first.valid? than bill.save, the tax sum gets added to database(I guess that is because of the associations are already in the database for this time.)

I am not sure if this is the best practice I am trying so I am open to any suggestions to change my approach. But anyway to get associated tax ids in after_validation callback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could not get ids in your callbacks as they are not persisted in your database yet and you want to join which will never work since no records. **after_save** callback will reserve an id to the record but you cannot get that unless after_commit your new data. Only persisted records have ids.

---

you have two cases

1. Continue with your design that BillLine and taxes are many_to_many association.
2. Change your association to one to many **"BillLine has_many taxes and each tax belongs only to one billLine"**

---

**Solution** :

- **Case 1 :**

  - Build your bill_line_taxes in your new action and **build taxes from it**.
  - Add accept_nested_attributes to your BillLineTax Model.
  - in your create action just BillLine.new(params) then save.
  - Your form must be nested.

ex

```
f.fields_for :bill_line_items do |s|
  s.fileds_for :taxes do ....
```

This will help you build the whole records without saving them so bill_line_tax will have a tax record built with it change your loop to

```
self.bill_line_taxs.each do |bill_line_tax|
  rate = bill_line_tax.tax.tax_rate
  self.grand_total = self.grand_total + ( rate / 100 ) * self.grand_total
end
```

- **Case 2 :**
  if it was one to many like i said your code will just work find.

  ```
  class BillLine < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :bill, inverse_of: :bill_lines
    has_many :taxes
    validates_associated :taxes

    validates :bill, presence: true
    validates :quantity, presence: true, numericality: true
    validates :price, presence: true, numericality: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :taxes, allow_destroy: true 

    after_validation :calculate_totals

    def calculate_totals
      self.total = self.price * self.quantity
      self.grand_total = self.total
      self.taxes.each do |tax|
        rate = tax.tax_rate
        self.grand_total = self.grand_total + ( rate / 100 ) * self.grand_total
      end
      self.tax_total = self.grand_total - self.total
      true
    end

  end
  ```

in your form

```
f.fields_for :taxes do |s|
  // taxes attributes
```

---

f for the the parent object which is BillLine in your case or whatever you handle your form. But make sure the it is nested exactly like i illustrated to get the built objects automatically in your callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the long and detailed answer but the problem is with your solution is I cannot define taxes in one-to-many relation because each customer have to be able to define their own taxes. And predefined taxes have to be reusable. Tax id's are posted due to accepts_nested_attributes_for. I should probably do it in controller because I can the attributes there.

Comment: You are talking about case 2 so what about case 1 ? , you can do it in the controller yes but the best practise is to do it in the life cycle of the created object.

Comment: Sir I am having difficulties to understand solution 1. That is a rails api so I am not using form helpers. Here is my current parameter hash:
params.require(:bill).permit(:document_no, :vendor_id, :currency_id,
        :date, :due_date, :notes, :total, :tax_total, :grand_total, :invoice_status_id,
        {
          bill_lines_attributes:
          [
            :id, :product_id, :description, :quantity, :price,:total,:tax_total,:grand_total
            {
              bill_line_taxes_attributes: [ :id, :bill_line_id, :tax_id ]
            }
          ]
        } )

Comment: In what way do you suggest me to change it?